# options is not defined in qTip2

Tags: qtip2

I've got Uncaught ReferenceError: options is not defined.

Here is the code:

```
// Create the tooltips only when document ready
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // MAKE SURE YOUR SELECTOR MATCHES SOMETHING IN YOUR HTML!!!
    $('a').qtip({
        content: {
            title: {
                text: 'text',
                button: 'close'
            },
            text: 'asfaf'
        },
        hide: {
            fixed: true,
            delay: 300
        },
        position: {
            my: 'left center',
            at: 'right center',
            target: 'event'
        }
    });
});
```

You can also visit http://jsfiddle.net/H4aTZ/2/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a problem regarding the title and position working together. Probably they are going to release a update soon.

Meanwhile, if you use nightly version it actually works :)
http://qtip2.com/v/nightly/